# Is there any way to mention interface as known types in wcf?

Tags: wcf, known-types

I am using wcf service, in that i need to return some complex object derived from the interface called IComponents, instead of mentioning concreate class as known type in service, is there any way to mention IComponents as known types in wcf?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think you can only specify a concrete class, because soap needs to know exactly what you're sending over the wire. I may be wrong.

Comment: I think you would need to come up with a custom serializer for your messages.

Comment: class or struct only for known type